# Babel Unexpected Token Export After Compile

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have created a project using ES6 syntax.

I am using Babel to compile the ES6 syntax JavaScript files to a version Node.js can run.

However, when I try to execute a file (index.js) that I believed to be compiled by babel, using `node lib/index.js`. I get the following error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`.

I run the following [command to compile](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#compile-directories) my project: `./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d lib`. `src` contains all of my files that are written in ES6.

It successfully compiles the directory with the message: `Successfully compiled 15 files with Babel.`

So, I am unsure as to why I am unable to run the compiled files. This is also my first time using babel so I may have missed something.

I have the following files which I believe are important to babel:

`.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

`package.json` - dev dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6"
}
```

Detailed error message:

```
/Users/c/Projects/Project1/src/credentials.js:10
export default Credentials;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/c/Projects/Project1/lib/index.js:3:53)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

It looks like in lib/index.js, it is referencing the ES6 file with the line:

`var _credentials = _interopRequireDefault(require("../src/credentials"));`.

Answer (score 0):

In the local environment, you can just install these packages.

```
npm install @babel/core @babel/node --save-dev
```

And then in your package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --exec babel-node src/index.js"
  }
```

And .babelrc the same you have already.
And it should work.

Comment: The only problem I see with the solution that you provided is when I come to deploy to production. As per, babel's documentation I should not be using @babel/node in production. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-node.html